# Adding hover event to elements inside a tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a tinymce plugin that populates the editor with content.

Certain populated elements have a class="hoverable"

I'd like to attach a function to the hover event on those elements with class="hoverable"

I know how to attach an onClick with ed.onClick.add in the create function but there is no ed.onHover.add or ed.onMouseIn.add.

Edit:
My plug-in actually pops up a dialog when you press the plug-in button in the menu. The user selects some content from the dialog and inserts it into the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a mouseover handler to elements in the editor with class 'hoverable'.

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('.hoverable').hover(function (evt){ /* do tooltip here */   });
```

You can find a howto create simple tooltips using [jQuery here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20hover%20tooltip&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://3nhanced.com/javascript/simple-tooltip-powered-by-jquery/&ei=p8anTtvEDOr74QSK76zcDw&usg=AFQjCNEMPTTnZlmmiNsQfyWlusMYrv3G5g&cad=rja).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would work if the content was already in the editor when the create function is called on the plugin. I didn't really make it clear in the question but in my case the content isn't put in until after a user selects it from a pop up that is initiated by pressing the plug-in's button in the menu. I ended up doing something pretty similar to this (you can see my answer if you care).

Answer (score 2):

In the function that adds the selected content to the editor I added

```
tinymce.activeEditor.$('.hoverable').live('mouseover mouseout', function(evt) {
    if (evt.type == 'mouseover') {
        //do hover stuff
    }
    else {
        //undo hover stuff
    }
}
```

In my case new hoverable things may be added so I need the .live in other cases you could probalby just use .hover.