# Target elements in TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

What is the best way to target elements (say all images of a given class) in the TinyMCE 4 editor.  I found some older solutions (i.e. [Adding hover event to elements inside a tinymce editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895082/adding-hover-event-to-elements-inside-a-tinymce-editor)), however, they apply to TinyMCE 3.  Note that elements can be added to the editor after initial rendering, so it would need something like jQuery's `on()` functionality.

One option might be to to do something like `$('#tinymce_id').contents()...`.

Or maybe when configuring TinyMCE, `tinymce.init({'selector': '#tinymce_id','setup' : function(ed) {do something here?}});`

Answer (score 5):

The best way I found to do it.

```
tinymce.init({
    'selector': "#tinymce_id",
    'setup' : function(ed) { 
        ed.on('init', function(e) {
            $(ed.getBody()).on("click", "img", function() {alert('hello');});
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this logic:

- Get TinyMCE text
- Convert it to a DOM (HTML) element
- Select anything using jquery
- Modify or do what you want with those elements selected
- Convert the html back to text
- set the content of the TinyMCE editor to the new html

```
//on click event
$("#test").click(function(){
    //get the text of the tinymce editor and convert it to an html element
    html = $.parseHTML(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());

    //do anything with the content here
    $(html).find("img.editor-img").css("width", "100px");

    //convert it back to text
    text = $(html).html();
    //add it to the tinymce
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(text);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rqwVA/1/

Comment: Very nice.  Let me go over it.

Comment: How would one initiate an event when an image was clicked?