# How do I get the checked state of a checkbox in the sourcecode in tinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using tinyMCE as a html-editor and I want to use checkboxes in my code where their toggled state is saved in the source-code.

Now I only get the state as how I defined in the beginnning, not after I toggled them in the editor.

#### code

This the code that I enter into tinyMCE, but the new state does not get reflected after I toggle the checkbox.

```
<textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" checked="checked" /> <label for="checkbox">check</label>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/> <label for="checkbox">no-check</label></div>
</textarea>
```

#### Codepen

I made [an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXEGvo) where you can check it out at codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the anwser found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774044/target-elements-in-tinymce-editor), I managed to find a solution.

I added a setup-function to TinyMCE.  I also added support for radiobuttons and selects.

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 500,
    theme: 'modern',
    setup : function(ed) {
        // This function works for checkboxes
        ed.on('init', function(e) {
            $(ed.getBody()).on("change", ":checkbox", function(el){
                if(el.target.checked){
                    $(el.target).attr('checked','checked');
                }else{
                    $(el.target).removeAttr('checked');
                }
            });
            // Radiobuttons
            $(ed.getBody()).on("change", "input:radio", function(el){
                var name =  'input:radio[name="'+el.target.name+'"]';
                $(ed.getBody()).find(name).removeAttr('checked');
                $(el.target).attr('checked','checked');
                $(el.target).prop('checked',true);
            });
            // Selects
            $(ed.getBody()).on("change", "select", function(el){
                $(el.target).children('option').each(function( index ) {
                    if(this.selected){
                        $( this ).attr('selected','selected');
                    }else{
                        $( this ).removeAttr('selected');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```